# Why using 0 as default non type template parameter for void* is not allowed

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, void

Why does the following code fail to compile?  Even though it is legal to do `void* ptr = 0;`

```
template <void* ptr = 0>
void func();

int main() {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

I ask because I found that a very trusted source did something similar and it failed to compile on my machine

**NOTE** Should have posted the compiler error along with my question so here it is

```
so_test.cpp:1:23: error: null non-type template argument must be cast to template parameter type 'void *'
template <void* ptr = 0>
                      ^
                      static_cast<void *>( )
so_test.cpp:1:17: note: template parameter is declared here
template <void* ptr = 0>
                ^
so_test.cpp:5:5: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
    func();
    ^~~~
so_test.cpp:2:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with ptr = nullptr]: null non-type template argument must be cast to template parameter type 'void *'
void func();
     ^
```

Comment: Please post the compiler output

Comment: "I found that a very trusted source did something similar" Can you tell us who and what?

Answer (score 9):

Template parameters of type `void*` are not allowed. See [temp.param]/4 in the standard, also summarized at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following (optionally *cv-qualified*) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.

Since `void` is not an object or function type, `void*` is not among the permitted types.

*Addendum:* A `void*` value known at compile time wouldn't be very useful. It's not possible to examine its value at compile time since `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed in constant expressions; nor is it possible to convert it to `T*` for some object type `T` at compile time.

Comment: I think this is wrong... `template<void * ptr = nullptr>` is very much allowed. The problem is not with `void *`, the problem is with `0`. `template<int * ptr = 0>` will not compile either.

Comment: @Petr'lapk'Budnik I'm afraid the C++ standard disagrees with you.

Comment: @Petr'lapk'Budnik I'm still convinced it's nonstandard even if GCC is allowing it---so we have no right to expect it to work in any given circumstance.

Comment: @petr I am afraid a compiler accepting code is only weak evidence that the code is legal.  Citations from the standard are much stronger.  Admittedly brian only has a cppreference quote, also weak evidence.

Comment: @Yakk the standard says the same thing. I will post a quotation shortly.

Comment: Well, I guess, standard and you, guys, are right and I am wrong. Thanks for the info! 
Does any compiler enforce that though? GCC does not, apparently. Nor does IBM. Clang? I mean, it looks to me that in OP compiler complains about `0` not being `nullptr`.
P.S. I'll leave my original erroneous comment.

Comment: Yep, I find I also need to `nullptr` instead of `0` there, at least eith some compilers, so I do it by habit.  I do not know if that is mandated by the standard, but is mostly harmless and increases acceptance, so...

Comment: @M.M No it isn't, it's an "object pointer" type, which means either "pointer to object" or *cv* `void*`. See [basic.compound]/3.

Comment: I tried gcc 4.8.5 and `clang-703.0.31` and this seems to work on both... Any ideas why they allow this?

Comment: @Curious good question, I don't know the answer to that. I'll post to std-discussion

Comment: @Brian What is std-discussion?  And could you link me to this?  I would love to have the link

Comment: @Brian According with this, even the form `template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, T>::value>* = nullptr>` would be illegal. The default type for `enable_if` is `void` and it is resolved in a `void*` non-type template parameter. Are you sure `void*` is not admitted? Because of [3.9.2/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-4), `void*` can be used as a pointer to object of unknown type, so it is admitted because of [14.1/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4). Am I wrong?

Comment: Note that the standard says also _The type of a pointer to cv void or a pointer to an object type is called an object pointer type._ So pointer to and object pointer are related.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to initialize a pointer with an `int`. Many implicit conversions, including integer-to-pointer conversions, don't happen in non-type template parameters.

The  [cppreference summary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments) of the behaviour in C++14 for non-template parameters of pointer to object type is:

> For pointers to objects, the template arguments have to designate the address of an object with static storage duration and a linkage (either internal or external), or a constant expression that evaluates to the appropriate null pointer or std::nullptr_t value.

So the code could be:

```
template <void* ptr = nullptr>
void f();
```

*Footnote:* it seems unclear whether `void *` is allowed as a parameter type, but compilers accept the above code.

Comment: Does this change in C++17?

Comment: @Yakk Not sure at this stage

Comment: maybe in here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html but my standardese literacy is not good enough to be sure without lots more thinking.  It seems to extend the allowed conversions, but is one of them `0` to null, and does it apply here?  I think yes to both, but not certain.

Comment: @Yakk going by cppreference: in C++17 the parameter can be "any converted constant expression of the type of the template parameter.", and the cppreference description of "converted constant expression" is expanded for C++17 but literal `0` to null pointer still doesn't appear to be in the list

Comment: "Pointer to object" type does *not* include `void*`. See [basic.compound]/3. "Object pointer" is not the same as "pointer to object".

Comment: @Brian ok... in the standard, "object pointer type" includes `void *` and "pointer to object type" excludes it.